# Redirect all section pages to one page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'de like to redirect all section pages to the section front page.

For example:

```
www.mysite.com/section/3/article
```

should redirect to

```
www.mysite.com/section/
```

How I can do this with htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/section/3/ http://www.mysite.com/section/index.html
```

This will redirect everything starting with `/section/3/` to `http://www.mysite.com/section/index.html`